# Kubernetes api-server command inaccessible?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

1. I am trying to access [kube-apiserver api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).
2. I wish to feed it with a file using [--admission-control-config-file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/#:%7E:text=admission%2Dcontrol%2Dconfig%2Dfile%20string) flag, to [enforce "baseline" Pod Security Standard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/enforce-standards-admission-controller/#:%7E:text=admission%2Dcontrol%2Dconfig%2Dfile).
3. I want to add [admission controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers)
4. Is it possible to create custom policy for admission controllers?

I ran `kubectl get pods --n kube-system` followed by `kubectl describe pod/kube-apiserver-test-control-plane -n kube-system` and I can see "Commands: kube-apiserver", but I am not sure what I can do with that.

Thanks!